# Plugin "Pull requests" for mercurial

Tags: mercurial, pull-request

Plugin with "pull-request" functionality for HG. Is there such plugin?

Comment: Plugin for what? What is *"pull-request" functionality*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pull requests are inherently a repository hosting-platform specific function, it isn’t something that can be added to Mercurial as an extension. How would you imagine that it should work?

If you’re looking for a Mercurial equivalent of GitHub pull requests; [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) offers free Mercurial hosting and has pull request functionality.

Comment: It has been a few years already that bitbucket removed support for mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be an extension directly named after that feature (the [GitHub "Pull Request"](https://github.com/blog/712-pull-requests-2-0)), but you could emulate it through an integration with a review system, as described in "[Review Board workflow for Mercurial repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851583/review-board-workflow-for-mercurial-repository)".

The [Mercurial Review Board extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ReviewboardExtension) ([repo here](http://code.google.com/p/mercurial-reviewboard/)) could be used to link your DVCS to [ReviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/), helping you to only pull what has been reviewed.